# Can't get background-image to show in this fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to practice my jquery and javascript. I was working on a fiddle that rotates remarks as the user clicks the arrow.png. But for some reason it's not showing and i can't test my code lol... I was going to add css animations to it as well to have it rotate rather than using javascript. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wrkmH/6/. What's wrong with my css that it isn't showing? I know this is a very noob question, sorry i just can't figure it out.
The html:

```
<p>I'm a <span id="remark">nice guy </span>.
   <a href="#" id="spinner" class ="anim"></a>
</p>
```

The css:

```
#spinner {
   height: 30px;
   background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/bfhwPv9.png');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   display: inline-block;    
}
```

Comment: You have `display: none;` in your fiddle.

Comment: Wrong edit of the fiddle. I updated it @dfsq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your css with the following one,

```
#spinner {
    height: 200px;
    width:  200px;
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/bfhwPv9.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;    
}
```

This would solve your problem.
keep coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The image you're loading "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONSTD.png" is 200px x 200px. You're currently setting the height to only 30px. If you set `#spinner` to the image dimension:

```
#spinner {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONSTD.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;    
}
```

You'll be able to see the spinner:  [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrkmH/7/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#spinner {
    height: 200px;
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/bfhwPv9.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display: block;    
}
```